# ASP.NET and background caching

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-services, backgroundworker, background-process

i have this insanely large database i want to print out data from, however since the database is pretty large, it normally takes about 10-20 minutes to execute from.

i really don't want the web people to wait that long for a page to show up, and was wondering if there was a way to pre-cache the sql data globally every 1 hour, for all to see?

i tryed to search google for aspx and background workers, and most anwsers i find, is that asp is not desgined for that, and i need to use a Windows service.. but as fare as i know, windows services does not support Web  Browser access? 
or is there a way to run a WebServer with ASPX from a Windows Service?

i never ever worked with aspx before, and got no idea what i am doing, however i have about 2000 hours in vb.net

Comment: If your query takes 20 minutes to execute then you need to work this around. Make for example a second temporary database, that is keep the final data in a flat table, update this flat data every 6hours, and just use that flat table to reads them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this MSDN article: [How to: Add Items to the Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61.aspx).

You probably want to add that data to the application cache, with a sliding expiration of 1 hour:

```
Cache.Insert("yourBigData", bigDataObject, _
    Nothing, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, _
    New TimeSpan(0, 60, 0))
```

Then, in your code, whenever you want to access that big data, check the cache first:

```
If(Cache("yourBigData") IsNot Nothing) Then
    ' Get your data out of the cache, and use that
    Dim yourBigData As DataTable = CType(Cache("yourBigData"), DataTable)
Else
    ' retrieve the data and add it to the cache again
End If
```

For a broader perspective, see [this MSDN article on "Caching Application Data"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6.aspx), especially this:

> ASP.NET has a powerful, easy-to-use caching mechanism that allows you
>   to store objects in memory that require extensive server resources to
>   create

That seems like precisely your scenario.

Comment: My apologies if the VB.NET code has syntax errors - I do not write VB much anymore.

Comment: thanks for the solution, main problem is, that it would proberly still make the site slow, when it need to update the cache data, or have i missed something?

Comment: You are correct, this would just cause the slowness problem to be less frequent.  Aristos left a good comment on the question with a different approach (utilize the database to make the query less expensive).

Comment: @Droa I forgot to ping you in my last comment.  See above.

Comment: i might need to make a wcf service to buffer the accumulated data, and fetch them with my asp.net application, i might work, right?

Comment: @Droa I actually haven't orked with WCF services at all, so I don't know.  You could run a Windows Service that buffers the accumulated data in a "flat" table (as Aristos described) that is optimized for very fast selects.  Also, I imagine no single client wants to see all of this 20 minutes worth of data at once, right?  Maybe you could just select the window the user wants to see (like in paging).